# MySQL query execution on remote server with output to be saved locally to a file

Tags: mysql, remote-access

```
CMD="use metadata; select * from usernames; select * from personData; select usernames.SNo, 
usernames.DataTelid, usernames.UName, personData.ActiveInactive from usernames, personData where usernames.DataTelid=personData.DataTelid into outfile '/tmp/querydb';"
ssh [USER-NAME]@[REMOTE-HOST] 
mysql -h HOST  -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -e "$CMD"  < /tmp/querydb
```

From server A, I login to server B which has the mysql database. The querydb file is snot suppose to be created on server B but server A. I am stuck and how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see two issues:

1. You're ssh'ing into server B, obtaining a shell there, and then executing the mysql command. No amount of output redirection performed on server B will be able to get files back to server A.
2. Your output redirection is going in the wrong direction.

Try this:

```
ssh user@host "mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -e \"$CMD\"" > /tmp/querydb
```

Comment: do you mean like this?                                                       CMD="use itTools; select * from usernames; select * from personData; select usernames.SNo, usernames.DataTelid, usernames.UName, personData.ActiveInactive from usernames, personData where 
usernames.DataTelid=personData.DataTelid;"
ssh user@host "mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -e \"$CMD\"" > /tmp/querydb

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ErickA I am trying to find the meaning of:   diff filename 1 filename2 | grep '^[<>]' | sed "s/^> \(.*\)/\1 some string/;"

Comment: @PiyushSaxena Post another question. Do not use comments for anything other than, well, comments.